# Trouble integrating a radical in the denominator for $ \int{x \over \sqrt{8-2x^2}}dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Currently trying to tackle MIT's 18.01 OCW 3rd problem set.

Problem 3A-2e: Compute the indefinite integral:

$$
\int{x \over \sqrt{8-2x^2}}dx
$$

**My solution**

Restate the problem as $\int x(8-2x^2)^{-1/2}dx$.

Via substitution or what they call advanced guessing, arrive at a solution of 
$${-1 \over 2}(8-2x^2)^{1/2} + c$$

**OCW's Solution**

Guess $(8-2x^2)^{3/2}$ for the non-constant term.
Looks good, but it needs a coefficient to get it in the final form: $${-1 \over 6}(8-2x^2)^{3/2} + c$$

**My confusion**

It appears that if the OCW had restated the problem, it would have done so as $(8-2x^2)^{1/2}$, which is to say that they seem to have addressed only the denominator of the total function. I cannot figure out what happens to the $x$ numerator, nor the status of the radical term as the denominator of a fraction.

I am at such a loss, I began to suspect a typo, but I thought the best thing would be to ask others. The OCW forum is just about useless. Thanks in advance, folks.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the problem set?  You can see that your solution is correct by taking the derivative.  The other answer gives the indefinite integral of $x\sqrt{8-2x^2}$.

Comment: Thank you, yes that's what I'm computing, as well.
Problem set: http://bit.ly/1g8jeNs [pdf]
Solutions: http://bit.ly/17p75Bq [pdf]
At: http://bit.ly/1ceVouD 
The question at hand is 3A-2(e)

Comment: They are applying change of variable $\int f(g(x))g'(x)dx=\int f(y)dy$. As you can see, the $g'(x)$ in the left hand side kind of disappears. This $g'(x)$ is the $x$ in the numerator.

Comment: @ABC, would you please expand a bit on that? Jonas described a solution exactly like what I had done, and so I'm quite sure that my original confusion was due to a simple typo on the problem set. I don't quite understand your comment, and I am unclear on ideas like "kind of disappears". Would appreciate if you had the time to be a more explicit, maybe in an answer proper, where you can plug in everything so a lug like me can get it. Thanks if ya can.

Comment: I thought you were asking something else.

Comment: @Luke thanks for posting this. I had the same confusion. Did you ever find a way to report this error? I haven't.

Answer (score 2):

You can see that your solution is correct by taking the derivative.  The other answer gives the indefinite integral of $x\sqrt{8-2x^2}$.  You can see this by taking the derivative of $-\frac16 (8-2x^2)^{3/2}$.

The solution you have now linked to has several errors.  First was misreading the problem, or somehow turning $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt u}$ into $u^{1/2}$.  Then in the second method, the derivative of $-2x^2$ was incorrectly given as $-4x^2$, then at the next step $x^2$ disappeared to get a result that matches neither the original integrand nor their mistaken integrand.

Comment: Thank you for the affirmation. That's exactly what I'd done and the indefinite integral I computed for the "official" answer. I suppose I just didn't believe they'd have a typo posted for years on end.